# Handling exceptions in interface in java

Tags: java, interface

I want to ask is it a good practice or advisable to handle exceptions in an interface? For example:

```
 public interface myInterface{
  String readFile() throws IOException;
  String printValues() throws IOException;
}
```

is this a good way to handle exceptions?

Comment: Depends on the situation. If an exception may occur in the method, and you want the client of that interface to handle it, then yes. Keep in mind, you are not handling the exception in the interface. You are requiring the client of that interface to handle an exception if one occured.

Comment: Define _handle exceptions_.

Comment: Is it a good practice? Isn't it a code to an implementation?

Comment: There is no reason why methods defined in an interface are not allowed to throw a checked exception; so, "good practice" here depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Vince Emigh for a nice description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface method in Java can declare that a method throws a particular exception. This is a best practice (when not overused) since the interface defines what class of exception can be thrown.

Checked exceptions by design require the caller to use try-catch or declare throws on the method. If a method in an interface does not declare an exception then an implementation of that interface cannot override the method and throw a checked exception. Implementation classes throwing unchecked exceptions (RuntimeException or their subclasses) could become potential errors downstream if not properly documented or understood. For **commonly occurring exceptions** it is best practice to declare the exception in the interface. Many of the java.io interfaces follow this best practice.

Example:

```
public interface Closeable {

  void close() throws IOException;

}
```

For more details see this tutorial discussing checked vs unchecked exceptions.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

See related question:
[Handling exceptions with interfaces and classes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027463/handling-exceptions-with-interfaces-and-classes-in-java?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Depends, if you think it will be useful for caller to know what exceptions can be thrown by the overriding classes and client can handle it appropriately e.g. Showing a message to user.

e.g. You have an ATM application and withdraw method throws two custom exceptions, InvalidPinException and InsufficientBalanceException then client can handle these exceptions as a caller and show user appropriate messages.

Throwing these exceptions from interface means all implementations can throw these and as a caller either you have to handle or re throw.